# Taking a list of strings, some of the objects have spaces. How to split just those objects and make them a separate object in the list

Tags: python, split

Let's say I have a list:

```
lista = ['dog', 'cat', 'red blue']
```

And I want to split the 'red blue' to 'red', 'blue':

```
lista = ['dog', 'cat', 'red', 'blue']
```

How could I go about doing that? I've tried:

```
for x in lista:
    lista.split()
```

But this doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: have you really tried that? that code cant even run, cant split a list.

Comment: Read the documentation: `split` returns a list of the items split; it does *not* alter the original object.

Comment: Another exact same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808592/splitting-each-string-in-a-list-at-spaces-in-python)

Comment: A third exact same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465661/how-can-i-replace-a-text-delimited-string-list-item-with-multiple-list-items-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
for x in lista:
    lista.split() # lista should be x?
```

would not change anything because you didn't save the result of split. This will help:

```
new_list = []
for x in lista:
    new_list += x.split()
lista = new_list # overwrite lista
```

However, there is also a one-liner to do the same:

```
lista = [y for x in lista for y in x.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than explicitly looping through with a for loop, I'd do something like this:

```
lista = ['dog', 'cat', 'red blue']
items = ' '.join(lista)  # combines lista into a string separated by spaces
lista = items.split(' ')  # splits the string by space into a list
```

You can do it in one line:

```
lista = ' '.join(lista).split(' ')
```

Comment: This solution is twice as fast as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lista = ['dog', 'cat', 'red blue']

y = []
for x in lista:
    y += x.split()

print(y)  # ['dog', 'cat', 'red', 'blue']
```